# Mirth -- Dynamically Change Polling Time on Channel

Tags: javascript, java, mirth, mirth-connect

I am working on automating a channel in mirth 3.3.1. I have 3 channels for ease of use I will label them primary and secondary. I have a 3rd channel built to monitor the primary and secondary channels.

The primary will send data downstream to an application I do not need to start the secondary until the downstream application has completed processing.

All my current configuration works, however, we have no way of verifying that processing is complete with the downstream app. What I am trying to accomplish is after the primary channel has processed its last message is to change the source poll setting time of the secondary channel.

The script will need to:

```
//Ensure channel is stopped
//Set Secondary channel Poll Time to 2 hours from now
//Redeploy secondary channel
//Start secondary channel
```

This will allow time for the downstream app to process and then run other data through the secondary channel.

I can complete everything except changing the polling time on the FileReader channel (secondary). I can not locate the correct JAVA Package to complete this on the web. And it may not be possible, but wanted to take another approach if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The secondary channel should be set to 2-hour polling interval and disable poll on start for secondary.

I initially thought this would not work, but after testing it works as I wish. The 2-hour interval starts when the channel is started.